# Two flutter apps for Windows, one shared runtime - is this possible?

Tags: windows, flutter, dll, runtime

I'm going to build a few .exe files with flutter. And each of them will contain 5Mb of runtime. Does flutter allow to separate the core and to build it as a shared library, like in CPP or Delphi? What will be the size of each executable in that case?

I tried to google it and chatgpt it, but looks like such approach is not very popular...